# Python multiprocessing: with and without pooling

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand Python's multiprocessing, and have devised the following code to test it:

```
import multiprocessing

def F(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return F(n-1)+F(n-2)

def G(n):
    print(f'Fibbonacci of {n}: {F(n)}')

processes = []
for i in range(25, 35):
    processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=G, args=(i, )))

for pro in processes:
    pro.start()
```

When I run it, I tells me that the computing time was roughly of 6.65s.

I then wrote the following code, which I thought to be functionally equivalent to the latter:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def F(n):
    if n == 0: return 0
    elif n == 1: return 1
    else: return F(n-1)+F(n-2)

def G(n):
    print(f'Fibbonacci of {n}: {F(n)}')

in_data = [i for i in range(25, 35)]

pool = ThreadPool(10)

results = pool.map(G, in_data)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

and its running time was almost 12s.

Why is it that the second takes almost twice as the first one? Aren't they supposed to be equivalent?

(NB. I'm running Python 3.6, but also tested a similar code on 3.52 with same results.)

Comment: How did you `join` the first version?

Comment: I didn't. Should I have?

Comment: How do you know the processes completed? From what I remember, start doesn't tell you when the process is done, so I'm assuming theres some code after what you're showing.

Comment: Well, there's no further code. Since the G(F()) functions perform as requested, I thought there wasn't anything wrong.

Comment: Indeed, if I add `pro.join` to the last for-loop in the first version of the code, the running time duplicates.

Comment: So that solves the mystery?

Comment: Does it? I don't understand what's going on. Why would I want to join the processes if that duplicates running time?

Comment: Do you understand how `join` works? Starting a process happens asynchronously. To make sure it completes you have to interact with it. It is a different process. If you want to create similar code you can use `map_async` and not join it. Not sure what good it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the second takes twice as long as the first is likely due to the CPython Global Interpreter Lock.

From http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/multicore_python.html:

> [...] the GIL effectively restricts bytecode execution to a single core, thus rendering pure Python threads an ineffective tool for distributing CPU bound work across multiple cores.

As you know, `multiprocessing.dummy` is a wrapper around the `threading` module, so you're creating threads, not processes. The Global Interpreter Lock, with a CPU-bound task as here, is not much different than simply executing your Fibonacci calculations sequentially in a single thread (except that you've added some thread-management/context-switching overhead).

With the "true multiprocessing" version, you only have a single thread in each process, each of which is using its own GIL. Hence, you can actually make use of multiple processors to improve the speed.

For this particular processing task, there is *no* significant advantage to using multiple threads over multiple processes. If you only have a single processor, there is no advantage to using *either* multiple processes *or* multiple threads over a single thread/process (in fact, both merely add context-switching overhead to your task).

(FWIW: A `join` in the true `multiprocessing` version is apparently being done automatically by the python runtime so adding an explicit `join` doesn't seem to make any difference in my tests using `time(1)`. And, by the way, if you *did* want to add `join`, you should add a *second* loop for the `join` processing. Adding `join` to the existing loop will simply serialize your processes.)